# How to move cursor in uitextfield to second character when user types

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to make it that the user can't delete the first character or insert a new first character as well as when the user try's to insert a new first character to move the cursor to the second character.

I've achieved the first part by the following.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if (range.length == 1 && range.location == 0 && string == ""){
            return false
        }
        if (range.length == 0 && range.location == 0 && string != ""){
            return false
        }
    return true
}
```

But this results in the user getting stuck on the first character unable to type anything unless they move the pointer themselves.

How do I achieve the second part of moving the cursor to the second character position so the user can begin to type from the second character?

Comment: are you giving your own fixed first character or you want it to remain empty?

Comment: I am giving it a fixed character that can't be removed by user.

Answer (score 0):

```
let newPosition = textField.endOfDocument;
self.yourtextFieldName.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: newPosition, to: newPosition);
```

Comment: This is close to what i want. If there is just one fixed character lets say a ? then if the user types it does what I want but if there is a ?z then the cursor should move to between the ? and the z but it moves it to the end of the document.

Answer (score 0):

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if let text = textField.text {
        if range.location == 0 && range.length == 1 {
            return false
        }
        if range.location == 0 && text.characters.count > 0 {
            let position = textField.position(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, offset: 1)!
            textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: position, to: position)
        }
    }
    return true
}
```